# Corosync fails to build in slackware

Tags: build, ld, nss, slackware

I'm trying to build corosync 2.3.4 from source in a slackware 14.1 (32 bits).

The vanilla configuration can't find the **nss** package (**mozilla-nss-3.15.2-i486-2.txz**) headers so I had to set CPPFLAGS before config to "-I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/nss/ -I/usr/include/nspr/".

Now I'm getting the following errors in the linking stage:

```
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_DigestFinal'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `SECITEM_FreeItem'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_ImportSymKey'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_DigestBegin'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_DigestOp'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_DestroyContext'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_CipherOp'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_CreateContextBySymKey'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_GenerateRandom'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_ParamFromIV'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `NSS_NoDB_Init'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_FreeSlot'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PK11_GetBestSlot'
./.libs/libtotem_pg.so: undefined reference to `PR_GetError'
```

My wild guess is that it can't find the nss lib (*libnss*.so*). I already tried setting LDFLAGS to "-l/usr/lib/libnss3.so" before config and also with LIBS="-L/usr/lib" with negative results.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the path to libraries with `-l`, just the name of the library without the leading "lib" part. Thus try with:

> LDFLAGS="-lnss3"

If a library you want to link is not in the library path (i.e.: not in /etc/ld.so.conf), you can specify the path with `-L`, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was a dependency problem. You can check the problem solving trail in http://lists.corosync.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-September/003326.html